# Find all Wordpress posts that contain a certain word

Tags: php, wordpress, post

Without adding any tags or categories, I need a way to generate a page that lists all Wordpress posts containing the word, for example, "design" somewhere within them.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Comment: Any particular reason why you don't just link to a search result? (e.g. http://yourpage.com/?s=design)

Comment: +1 to above comment for the solution. However the answer to "Why one doesn't use search" is most probably that we didn't knew that WP search is so efficient.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [WP_Query](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to do a search:

```
<?php
$query = new WP_Query( 's=keyword' );

if ($query->have_posts()){
  while ( $query->have_posts() ) { $query->the_post();
    echo '<h2>';
      the_title();
    echo '</h2>';
    the_content();
  } //end while
}
```

Let me know how it went!